# Правильное условие для оператора if PHP

Tags: php, if

Изучаю PHP. Не могу понять, как правильно составить условие. Обработчик получает по GET 1 или 2 переменные phone (номер телефона) или name (имя владельца телефона). Как правильно обработать условие: Если пришел только номер то вывести только номер, если пришли и номер и имя то вывести и номер и имя. Сейчас, когда я отправляю и номер и имя, то сразу обрабатывается 1 условие, и PHP выводит, будто пришел только номер телефона:

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';

if (isset($_GET['phone'])){
    echo "only phone";
}elseif (isset($_GET['phone']) && isset($_GET['name'])){
    echo "get phone and name";
}
```

Comment: поменяйте блоки местами, сначала проверяйте на 2 условия, потом на 1

Comment: Только так можно сделать? Это самый правильный вариант решения такой задачи?

Comment: Если Вы напишите что хотите дальше сделать (после разделения), то возможно будут еще решения...

Comment: Дальше будет выборка по БД,если есть номер и имя - и пришло по GET новое имя, то поменять имя, если пришел только номер и такого номера нет в БД то добавить новый номер в БД

Comment: Сделать всегда можно десятком разных способов. Но блоки if проверяются строго по порядку и как только один блок сработал, остальные не выполняются. А так то можно конечно сделать и `if(phone) { if(name) { }  else {} }`

Answer (score 1):

Вот верная формулировка:

```
<?php

    include_once 'db.php';

    if (isset($_GET['phone']) && isset($_GET['name'])) {
        echo "get phone and name";        
    } else if (isset($_GET['phone'])) {
        echo "only phone";
    } else if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
        echo "only name";
    } else {
        echo "no get params";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

С утверждение об эквивалентности isset и empty абсолютно не согласен, ибо следуя из названия Empty - проверяет существование переменной и пустоту, в отличие от Isset которая проверяет только существование переменной, как то так.

Следую из этого, код будет примерно следующим, добавил маломальскую фильтрацию:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $result = array();
    if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) {
        $result[] = preg_replace('#[^0-9-\(\)\s\+]+#iS', '', strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
        if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
           $result[] = preg_replace('#[^a-zа-я\s]+#iS', '', strip_tags($_POST['name']));
        }
    }
    // Действия с массивом $result
}
```

Comment: А при чем здесь $_POST, я стесняюсь спросить?

Comment: на будущее - если так прям хочется валидации, то данные ннадо не молча нормализовывать, а проверять на наличие недопустимых символов и выбрасывать ошибку.

Comment: Тут показан пример исходя из вопроса! Комметировать конечно тоже хорошо, но может быть покажешь мастер класс для простых смертных ?

Answer (score -1):

Смотря что Вы собираетесь делать с этими данными:
Например. отобразить сразу:

```
 <?php
  echo (isset($_GET['name'])) ? $_GET['name'] : '';
  echo (isset($_GET['phone'])) ? $_GET['phone'] : '';
 ?>
```

... или использовать позже... :

```
<?php
$name = (isset($_GET['name'])) ? $_GET['name'] : '';
$phone = (isset($_GET['phone'])) ? $_GET['phone'] : '';
// ... ещё много кода ...
echo $name;
echo $phone;
?>
```

Могут ли быть ещё какие-то входные данные?:

```
<?php
 foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
      // Что-то делаем с данными
 }
?>
```

Comment: `while (isset($_GET)) {` WAT?

Comment: $$key = $value; - это называется register globals, и ОГРОМНАЯ дыра в безопасности.

Comment: @Ипатьев, с "while (isset($_GET)) { WAT?" согласен. Исправил.

Comment: if (isset($_GET)) - абсолютная бессмыслица. никогда так не пиши.

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну, а если это "голая" ссылка, без ?key=value, зачем обрабатывать $_GET, если его нет?

Comment: затем что ты не понимаешь что такое $_GET, и что такое "зачем обрабатывать". поверь на слово - просто никогда так не делай. Мало того что оно не будет работать так как ты ожидаешь, но плюс ко всему это ещё и бессмысленно.

Comment: И - да - обязательно проверяй свой код перед тем как его постить. при твоем уровне владения языком это обязательно.

Comment: Я даже не могу представить ситуации когда `isset($_GET)` вернет __false__. Кроме той когда кто-то намеренно вызовет `unset($_GET)`.

Comment: @Ипатьев, согласен. Будем считать это первой пробой. Хорошо. Но про бессмысленность - не совсем понятно. Логика между страницами бывает разная.

Comment: логика бывает разная, но заворачивать проверку гет параметров в проверку массива гет - бессмысленно. Это экономия на спичках

Comment: @Ипатьев, понял. Массив $_GET присутствует всегда, даже если он пустой. Проверил через $GLOBALS.

Answer (score -3):

желательно одновременно проверять"isset" и"empty". Если вы просто проверяете "isset", то условие выполняется, даже если оно у вас пустое. и "empty" проверяет, есть ли что-то внутри него или нет

```
if (isset($_GET['phone']) AND !empty($_GET['phone'])){
    echo "only phone";
}elseif (isset($_GET['phone'])  AND !empty($_GET['phone']) AND isset($_GET['name'])  AND  !empty($_GET['name'])){
    echo "get phone and name";
}
    ?>
```

Comment: зачем проверять isset и empty? Описание функции `empty` читали? Переменная считается пустой, если она **не существует** или её значение равно FALSE. `empty()` фактически является точным эквивалентом конструкции **!isset($var) || $var == false**

Comment: когда приходит имя и номер телефона из формы, я возвращаю "True" в пустом состоянии. Чтобы этого избежать, необходимо применять " empty

Comment: а зачем тогда `isset`, если применяется `empty`?

Comment: Потому что в вопросе "isset";. В общем, "empty" одновременно выполняет и функцию isset.

Comment: Тогда чтобы сократить код и требуется получать не пустые значения, лучше сразу использовать !empty?

Comment: Да Точно так же